# Why minified css files mess style when combined, but works when put in <head>?

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, minify

I have three minified css files, let's call them first.min.css, second.min.css and third.min.css. I have minified them with grunt cssmin. If I put them in  like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="first.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="second.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="third.min.css">
```

Everything works perfectly. How ever, if I either concat them with grunt or copy them by hand at a single css file in same order, the site falls apart.

What might cause that to happen? I have thought that css files are always read in a same order as they're either put on html head or in to a css files, but have I understood something wrong?

I also noticed, that the trouble seems to be somehow related to second.css and third.css. The only difference I could find was that they have media queries in. Could that affect how the files are read?

I also tried to combine the original css files to one big master and then minify it, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you SURE that there are no `// line comments` anywhere in the files? Could the minifier be adding such a line at the top or bottom, for example?

Comment: @ilikesleeping I went throught the files, no // line comments

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a basic thing and had nothing to do with the order.

There was a open curly bracket in one of the CSS files. The bug was at the end of the css file, so it didn't affect anything when the faulty file was loaded separately. However, when combined, the flaw messed up the rest of the css.

Added closing bracket } to the original file, minified it again and now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure grunt is not changing the order in the bundle. Check your config and make sure the minification has them in the right order. CSS will fail when you switch styles around.

Comment: I think I triple checked this, but I check it one more time. I checked the file, then I tried to copy paste by hand to one file to be 100% sure.